# changing img src of another div with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, function, onclick, click

I have a trouble changing the src of my image with jquery :

I have my div projectName with all the buttons which will be clicked on for changing the images. 
Those images will be contained in another div called projectImg.

But when I click on my buttons, nothing is happening. Someone know if there is a way to make my jquery work??

**EDIT :** Found the error ! I only needed to put a type="button" into my html buttons. Thanks for the help though  !

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.sliding').click(function(){
     var url_img = $(this).attr('id');
     $('#projImg img').attr('src',url_img)
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="galerie" class="galerie-section content-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        
          <div class="container-fluid projectName text-center col-sm-6" id="projName">
              <button id="img/img1.jpg" class="sliding" type="button">img1</button>
              <button id="img/img2.jpg" class="sliding" type="button">img2</button>
              <button id="img/img3.jpg" class="sliding" type="button">img3</button>  
          </div>
          
          <div class="container-fluid projectImg col-sm-6" id="projImg">  
            <img src="img/img1.jpg" class="img-fluid img-galerie">
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: That's not valid synthax, you are missing anonymous function wrapper as ready event parameter: `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: Your `div` `projectImg` has no `attr` `src`

Try with `$('#projImage').find('img').attr('src',url_img)` instead

Comment: Thank you for correcting me! But it still doesn't work with the .find('img'), could it be because there is a path to my image?

Comment: There are several issues needs to be corrected. Pointed them. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong selector - your selector is to div, not to img. This should be `$('#projImage img').attr('src',url_img)`

Comment: I tried it just know but it didn't change.. but thank you for helping !

Comment: I'm sure this works - I've just tested your changed code and this works as it should. Src attr is changing. Maybe your problem is that, you should change `id's` of buttons to `img/img1.jpg`, `img/img2.jpg`, `img/img3.jpg` (now you have only `img1`, `img2`, `img3`) ?

Comment: tried it to, but I seems that the button is not clickable, the src isn't changing either in the console?

Comment: I found it ! forgot to put into the button : type="button" ! Thank you very much for helping me though !!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple errors.

1) Ready function won't accept your direct function should be wrapped by `function(){}`

2) Your div directly do not have an src attribute. You have to find the image inside that and set.

3) Your id to the target div is wrong. Corrected.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.sliding').click(function(){
  debugger;
     var url_img = $(this).attr('id');
     $('#projImg').find("img").attr('src',url_img)
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="galerie" class="galerie-section content-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        
          <div class="container-fluid projectName text-center col-sm-6" id="projName">
              <button id="img1" class="sliding">img1</button>
              <button id="img2" class="sliding">img2</button>
              <button id="img3" class="sliding">img3</button>  
          </div>
          
          <div class="container-fluid projectImg col-sm-6" id="projImg">  test
            <img src="img/img1.jpg" class="img-fluid img-galerie">
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```